# Integer part of a positive real number exists and is unique

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking through Tao's Analysis I and came across this problem

> Prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb R^+,\exists!N\in\mathbb {N}$ s.t. $N\leqslant x<N+1$

I came up with a solution but I used the well-ordering of the natural numbers, which apparently is only treated later on in the book. I am wondering if anyone can suggest how else I should prove it.

My proof:
Let $x\in\mathbb R^+$.

Consider the set $S=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n>x\}$. Then $S\subseteq \mathbb N$.
Also $S\neq \emptyset$ by the Archimedean property ($\forall x,\varepsilon\in \mathbb R^+,\exists N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $N\varepsilon>x$, with $\varepsilon=1$ in this case).

Then by the well-ordering of $\mathbb N$ there exists a minimum $n_0\in S$, which is unique, $\forall n\in S, n_0\leqslant n $. We have $n_0>x>0$ so $n_0\geqslant 1$ which means that $n_0-1$ is defined.

Now $n_0-1\leqslant x$, for if $n_0-1>x$ then $n_0$ wouldn't be the minimal element of $S$.

So take $N=n_0-1$ and we have found a unique (by the uniqueness of the minimal element of $S$) $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $N\leqslant x<N+1$. **Q.E.D.**

As I said earlier, my question is if someone could suggest another method I could use to prove the statement. Furthermore I would be grateful if you point out errors that you find in my proof.

Comment: I think mathematical induction is allowed

Comment: Your argument seems sound. You might want to check with the Godfather, though.

Comment: @Amr yes I think so too, could you give an outline or suggestion how I could use induction though? It is not clear to me how I would do that, $x$ being arbitrary.

Comment: Is the set of natural numbers defined as the intersection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Sorry, I meant all inductive subsets of  $\mathbb{R}^+$ that contain $0$

Comment: @Amr I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. I will take a better look at it tomorrow as it is getting late now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MichaelCorleone: An inductive subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is a *non-empty* subset $ S $ of $ \mathbb{R} $ that satisfies the following property: $ (\forall x)((x \in S) \Longrightarrow (x + 1 \in S)) $. The assumption of non-emptiness is made in order to avoid having $ \varnothing $ as an inductive subset of $ \mathbb{R} $. An example of an inductive subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is $ \mathbb{R} $ itself. Another example is $ \mathbb{Z} $. If you consider all inductive subsets of $ \mathbb{R} $ that contain $ 0 $, then there is one that is contained in all others, namely, $ \mathbb{N}_{0} $.